# AWS PHP SDK - Loading only what I need

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am looking to use the AWS PHP SDK to handle some signed URLs for S3, per this article:

http://ceph.com/docs/next/radosgw/s3/php/

However, when I downloaded the SDK, it's huge. It's 9.6MB and over 1,000 files. Do I really need to copy all of those files to my server, or can I somehow customize my usage of the SDK to only load the parts I need to use S3? I don't have a lot of control over our production servers, so any solution that requires me to run some sort of tool/framework on a server might not be feasible for me.

Comment: Note that the SDK uses an autoloader, so only what you need is actually loaded into PHP memory, and only when you actually need to use it

Comment: My only thing is that I'll have to commit all those files into our repo. I was hoping that I could just copy a subset of those files and use those only.

Comment: Like I said, you __don't__ need to check thousands of files into your repo.... at most, you check a single file into your repo (the phar file); but if you use composer to handle your dependencies, you don't have to check any files beyond a composer.json file into your repo - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/installation.html

Answer (score 3):

It should also be available as a single `.phar` file (which includes all the dependencies of the SDL as well) - easier to copy one file than many - [Installing via phar](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/installation.html#installing-via-phar)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you don't have to upload those files you don't need. To get a list of the files you actually used you could:

- write a script doing some URL signing for you
- at the end of the script call [get_included_files](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) to get a list of files the autoloader included
- only copy those files to your production server

This may cause problems when something happens differently and other classes you previously didn't use a tried to be loaded. I'd therefore be generous and include whole feature folders if one of the files was included before. For example I'd upload the whole `vendor/guzzlehttp` folder even if you didn't include all of it's files.

Answer (score 0):

You might actually need to use v2 of the SDK, as Ceph might not support the new S3 authentication protocol used in v3. (The examples shown on the link you provided actually use v2 of the SDK, but v2 should still work.)

v2 is actually larger than v3 by several megabytes, but if you follow Mark Baker's suggestion to use the `phar` or deploy via composer, then you won't need to wait for 1,000+ to finish rsync-ing/scp-ing/sftp-ing.